# Mouseclick on Button

Tags: autoit

I wrote a minimalistic python program with tkinter which gives out a sample text when clicking a button. I now want to execute this program and click the button with autoit:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>

CalcTime()

Func CalcTime()
    Run("dist/min_tk_app.exe")
    Local $aPos = ControlGetPos("[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]", "", "Edit1")
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", $aPos)
    MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_LEFT, 324, 145, 1)
EndFunc
```

I received this info: `[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]`, through the *Autoit Window Info* application. I always just receive `0` as output for `$aPos`. Do you know why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `ControlGetPos` wrong.

```
ControlGetPos ( "title", "text", controlID )
```

`[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]` should be placed as `controlID` and dont forget the title of the window (important) !

Anyway, Instead of `ControlGetPos` and `MouseClick` you should use `ControlClick`

```
$WinTitle = "" ; put your window title here MANDATORY or it will use active window
$WinText = "" ;can be left empty
ControlClick($WinTitle, $WinText, "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you receive `0` as output for `$aPos` because the Window is not there yet. You could try to use [`WinWait`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm) before working on that window:

```
Run("dist/min_tk_app.exe")

; wait 10 seconds for the window to appear
WinWait("[CLASS:YourApp]", "", 10)

; maybe wait another second
Sleep(1000)

Local $aPos = ControlGetPos("[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]", "", "Edit1")
```

Answer (score 1):

If @mrt's solution doesn't work I would recommend using `ControlFocus`to set focus on the control and then `ControlSend` to send enter button on the control. Usually OK button is preselected. If that is not the case then you can send TAB until the button gets focus and the send enter.